# PHP code for SSE not working as it is supposed to do

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am here to ask you about a PHP file I've been coding. I am building a live auction website that lets the users take part to auctions, each one shown in a site's page. In order to let users know when someone else has made a bid, I have used a SSE system. I use AJAX for the user's bid action's registration on the database (when the user bids, the price of the item in the database gets higher to exactly 1 dollar more. The price is stored as current price + 100 in the database because I am only storing integers (the number of cents) for the prices, for security reasons).
My AJAX works well, so the bid actually happens.
My SSE connection gets opened as expected, at the moment of the page load. The javascript EventSource object successfully opens the stream to my PHP file, but I can't understand why, when I make a test bid in the auction's page using my AJAX, the PHP SSE worker doesn't send a message to the auction's page (that has opened the stream to the worker).
Here is the PHP code that is supposed to check whether there's a new bid and send a message to the auction's page containing the new bid's data.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$mysqli = new mysqli(* data *);
$listings = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id FROM listings WHERE schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'");

$to_check = array();
while ($li = $listings->fetch_array()) {
    $to_check[] = array($li["listing_id"], $li["price"], $li["buyer_id"]);
}

while (true) {
    $change = 0;
    $listings_2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id FROM listings WHERE schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'");
    $different = array();
    while ($li_2 = $listings_2->fetch_array()) {
        foreach ($to_check as &$li_check) {
            if ($li_check[0] === $li_2["listing_id"]) {
                if (intval($li_2["price"]) !== intval($li_check[1])) {
                    $li_check = array($li_2["listing_id"], $li_2["price"], $li_2["buyer_id"]);
                    $different[] = $li_check;
                    $change = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($change === 1) {
        echo "data: " . json_encode($different) . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
        flush();
    }
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

I hope you can follow how I reasoned to write this code: when the connection is opened, all the listings (that are the lots the auction is composed of) that are eligibile for taking part in the auction will be checked and stored in the array called `$to_check`. Every time the outer `while` loop iterates, the code sends a query to the database again to check if some price fields have been changed. In case it has happened, the code sends a message to the auction's page, in order to inform the user.

The problem is that, when I try to bid from the auction's page, the bid is successful but I do not receive any message from the PHP worker (that is supposed to tell me that the x listing price has changed). What is the problem with that PHP code?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. For clarity reasons, I will also write the Javascript code that handles the SSE system.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var evtSource = new EventSource("bidchecker.php");

    evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("onmessage");
      // etc.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What web server are you using? Have you made sure it's not buffering content? If you're using nginx and FastCGI, try `fastcgi_buffering off;` and `gzip off;`. Sending a `Content-Encoding: none` header from PHP should turn nginx gzip'ing off for this page alone. Additionally, certain php.ini settings can prevent output from being rendered immediately despite calling `flush()` (e.g. `zlib.output_compression`)

Comment: That's not the problem. I've noticed that, although there is the line header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
a MIME type error comes out ( EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.  ).

Comment: Have you checked your PHP logs for any notices, warnings, or errors? I'm guessing something is happening that's causing PHP to send output before you expected it to. Once output has been sent, you can no longer send `header()`s, which would explain why you're not seeing a MIME type of text/event-stream.

Comment: @JohnM. - you're a life saver .. the `Content-Encoding: none` works!